# AJAX using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code in index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ajax check</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

alert('working...');
$('#ibutton').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
alert('double click');      
$.ajax({
url: "page.html",
cache: false,
success: function(){
$("#message").val('ajax working..');
},
error: function(){
$("#message").val('error in the page');
}
});
}); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<form action="page.html">
<input type="button" id="ibutton" value="click here"/>
<div id="message"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In `page.html`, the only content is 'working...'
when I click the `click here` button... nothing happens.. what is wrong in the code?

Comment: For the doubt which is asked before 'when I click `click here` button.. nothing happerns' it is rectified by changing `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" > </script>` instead of `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" />` .. and using $(#message).text('ajax working..') instead of  $(#message).val('ajax working..') , script works fine and shows 'error in page'.. please rectify why it is displaying error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is the `val` function. I think that you want to use `text` function instead of `val`:

```
$("#message").text('ajax working..');
```

Comment: still that change `text` instead of `val` is not working. and event `alert('working');` is also not executed

Comment: Verify with other browser. I tested with chrome and it worked.

Comment: Nop. Only `val`to `text` and used chrome.

Comment: your tips worked.. but i have another problem facing.. please re-read the question..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22622/discussion-between-cobra-and-william-seiti-mizuta)